# SQL Server: How to return value for each past 6 months

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns a score on whether or not 3 of the columns = 1 and then if the `ProviderID` exists in the 2nd table. I need to be able to return a score for each month for 6 months using column `Time_Stamp`, not including current month. The below returns the score for last month. How can I include the remaining 5 months and `ROW_NUMBER()` them?

```
DECLARE @ProviderID int = '1717';

WITH cte as
(
    SELECT TOP 1 
       a.ProviderID, Time_Stamp,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [AdditionalReports] = '1' THEN 5 ELSE 0 END) as AdditionalReports,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [UniqueReportRequests] = '1' THEN 15 ELSE 0 END) as UniqueReportsRequests,
       SUM(CASE WHEN [SurveyCompleted] = '1' THEN 30 ELSE 0 END) as SurveyCompleted,
       MAX(CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END) as SubscriptionExists
    FROM 
       ProviderValueCard a
    LEFT JOIN 
       SubscriptionsTV b ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
    WHERE 
       a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
       AND Time_Stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND  DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
    GROUP BY 
       Time_Stamp, a.ProviderID, event
    ORDER BY 
        event DESC, Time_Stamp DESC
)
SELECT 
   ProviderID, Time_Stamp, 
   (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
FROM 
   cte
```

Here is how to grab the first/last day of previous months:

2 months ago:

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) as FirstD2monthsago,
        DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(GETDATE()), DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) AS last_day_2_months_ago
```

3 months ago etc:

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 3, 0) as FirstD3monthsago,
        DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(GETDATE()), DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())) AS last_day_3_months_ago
```

Desired output

```
ProviderID  Time_Stamp              TotalScore  Row_Number
----------- ----------------------- -----------
1717        2014-08-29 12:11:17.610 70              1
1717        2014-07-29 12:11:17.610 95              2
1717        2014-06-29 12:11:17.610 100             3
1717        2014-05-29 12:11:17.610 70              4
1717        2014-04-29 12:11:17.610 70              5
1717                                                6
```

Comment: Why did you delete the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668997/sql-server-including-each-of-last-6-months?noredirect=1#comment40114729_25668997) and repost it again?

Comment: Could you help me piece it together? I'm not sure what I'm joining each time or where to include the ROW_NUMBER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @ProviderID INT, @Now DATETIME, @Months INT
SELECT @ProviderID  = 1717, @Now = GETDATE(), @Months = 5

WITH 
date_range_cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,-1,@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,0,@Now) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.RowNum + 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,(-d.RowNum - 1),@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,-d.RowNum,@Now) AS EndDate
    FROM date_range_cte d
    WHERE d.RowNum + 1 <= @Months
    ),
    main_cte AS (
            SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProviderID, d.RowNum, d.StartDate ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC) AS ordinal_position,
            a.ProviderID, 
            d.RowNum, 
            d.StartDate,
            [AdditionalReports] * 5 AS AdditionalReports,
            [UniqueReportRequests] * 15 AS UniqueReportsRequests,
            [SurveyCompleted] * 30 as SurveyCompleted,
            CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END as SubscriptionExists
            FROM ProviderValueCard a
            INNER JOIN date_range_cte d ON d.StartDate < Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp <= d.EndDate 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SubscriptionsTV b ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
            WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
            )  
        SELECT ProviderID, RowNum, StartDate, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM main_cte
        WHERE ordinal_position = 1
        ORDER BY RowNum
```

Comment: Jim, the table may have multiple entries per month and to prevent duplicate adding I was selecting only the `top 1` when ordering by `Time_Stamp`. I'm playing with it figure it out but how could I prevent this?

Comment: I'm also not sure how the scores are being added. June should 100(highest score), but is 500 and there's only 1 entry for the month

Comment: I updated the solution.  If the three fields are bits you may have to convert them to integers.  If they are nullable, you may have to  apply isNull.

Comment: It looks like its only grabbing one instance and not duping but I don't believe it's the most recent however. The scores are 100 and below but incorrect...The StartDate is grabbing a time stamp that isn't even in the 1st table for that month. I'm assuming it's being confused bc the event column from the first table is a datetime time stamp also in which the ProviderID can also have multiple entries.

Comment: It's just not grabbing the most recent. So for August, the most recent score adds to 95. But this query spits out 100 for august, there is a 100 record for that month. Testing other months with just 1 record does return the correct score

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways (psuedocode):

1 - Make a cte just like your existing one for each month you want to get.   The only thing you need to change in each one is this line:

```
AND Time_Stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0) AND  DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE())
```

For 2 months ago, you would change it to this:

```
AND Time_Stamp BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 2, 0) AND  DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
```

and so on for the other months back.

2 -  Referring to the same line in your cte above, change it to a -6 to get data for the past 6 months.  Then include a MONTH(TimeStamp) column in your select list and group by it to get one row per month for the past 6 months.

Comment: Could you structure a query for me for the first 2 months? I don't know what to select/pass on from the previous cte

Comment: That's basically what I've done.  The first line is from the CTE for the previous month to date, and the second line is from the CTE for the month before that.

Comment: I included that in my question...I'm already grabbing the last month anyway