# SQL Server: How to not subtract 1 month with DATEADD

Tags: sql-server

The query below returns a calculated `TotalScore` and returns them by date. Everything is correct except all the dates are 1 month behind of what they should be. So Jan is showing as Dec but is still returning the correct score for Jan as are the rest of the months. I'd like to keep as much of the query intact as possible but just stop returning -1 month.

```
    DECLARE @ProviderID INT, @Now DATETIME, @Months INT

    SELECT @Now = GETDATE(), @Months = 5;

WITH 
date_range_cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,-1,@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,0,@Now) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.RowNum + 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,(-d.RowNum - 1),@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,-d.RowNum,@Now) AS EndDate
    FROM date_range_cte d
    WHERE d.RowNum + 1 <= @Months
    ),
    main_cte AS (
            SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProviderID, d.RowNum, d.StartDate ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC) AS ordinal_position,
            a.ProviderID, 
            d.RowNum, 
            d.StartDate,
            [AdditionalReports] * 5 AS AdditionalReports,
            [UniqueReportRequests] * 15 AS UniqueReportsRequests,
            [SurveyCompleted] * 30 as SurveyCompleted,
            CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END as SubscriptionExists
            FROM ProviderValueCard a
            INNER JOIN date_range_cte d ON d.StartDate < Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp <= d.EndDate 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SubscriptionsTV b ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
            --WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
            WHERE a.ProviderID = 874 AND GroupID = 2
            )  
        SELECT ProviderID, RowNum, StartDate, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM main_cte
        WHERE ordinal_position = 1
        ORDER BY RowNum
```

Result

```
ProviderID  RowNum      StartDate               TotalScore
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
874         1           2014-12-30 10:45:22.000 95
874         2           2014-11-30 10:45:22.000 80
874         3           2014-10-30 10:45:22.000 55
874         4           2014-09-30 10:45:22.000 100
874         5           2014-08-30 10:45:22.000 50
```

Desired Result

```
ProviderID  RowNum      StartDate               TotalScore
----------- ----------- ----------------------- -----------
874         1           2015-01-30 10:45:22.000 95
874         2           2014-12-30 10:45:22.000 80
874         3           2014-11-30 10:45:22.000 55
874         4           2014-10-30 10:45:22.000 100
874         5           2014-09-30 10:45:22.000 50
```

Table `ProviderValueCard` where values are pulled. Can see the dates there.

```
    ProviderID  AdditionalReports UniqueReportRequests Time_Stamp              AdditionalReportsNum UniqueReportsNum SessionsProgress AdditionalReportsNumQtr UniqueReportsNumQtr SurveyCompleted
    ----------- ----------------- -------------------- ----------------------- -------------------- ---------------- ---------------- ----------------------- ------------------- ---------------
    874         0                 1                    2015-01-30 08:13:44.660 0                    55               3                0                       10                  1
    874         0                 0                    2014-12-30 08:31:20.893 0                    0                3                0                       0                   1
    874         1                 0                    2014-11-30 09:17:34.280 55                   0                0                20                      0                   0
    874         1                 1                    2014-10-30 10:17:52.940 5                    5                3                5                       5                   1
    874         0                 0                    2014-10-30 10:17:17.437 0                    0                1                0                       0                   1
    874         0                 0                    2014-09-30 10:20:56.163 0                    0                0                0                       0                   0
    874         0                 0                    2014-08-30 10:21:58.283 0                    0                0                0                       0                   0
```

A little context to where I got to the query though I need to keep the current month and score included:[SQL Server: How to return value for each past 6 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671505/sql-server-how-to-return-value-for-each-past-6-months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add EndDate to main_cte and use it instead of StartDate in the select.

```sql
DECLARE @ProviderID INT, @Now DATETIME, @Months INT

SELECT @Now = GETDATE(), @Months = 5;

WITH 
date_range_cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,-1,@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,0,@Now) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d.RowNum + 1 AS RowNum, DATEADD(mm,(-d.RowNum - 1),@Now) AS StartDate, DATEADD(mm,-d.RowNum,@Now) AS EndDate
    FROM date_range_cte d
    WHERE d.RowNum + 1 <= @Months
    ),
    main_cte AS (
            SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProviderID, d.RowNum, d.EndDate ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC) AS ordinal_position,
            a.ProviderID, 
            d.RowNum, 
            d.EndDate,
            [AdditionalReports] * 5 AS AdditionalReports,
            [UniqueReportRequests] * 15 AS UniqueReportsRequests,
            [SurveyCompleted] * 30 as SurveyCompleted,
            CASE WHEN b.ProviderID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 50 END as SubscriptionExists
            FROM ProviderValueCard a
            INNER JOIN date_range_cte d ON d.StartDate < Time_Stamp AND Time_Stamp <= d.EndDate 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SubscriptionsTV b ON a.ProviderID = b.ProviderID  
            --WHERE a.ProviderID = @ProviderID AND GroupID = 2
            WHERE a.ProviderID = 874 AND GroupID = 2
            )  
        SELECT ProviderID, RowNum, EndDate, (AdditionalReports + UniqueReportsRequests + SurveyCompleted + SubscriptionExists) AS TotalScore
        FROM main_cte
        WHERE ordinal_position = 1
        ORDER BY RowNum
```